# Converting undefined indexes to null in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm not sure if the title of this question is necessarily the accurate description of what I need to do, but I'll go ahead and ask my question and see what everyone thinks...

Basically, I am receiving data from a source that I have no control over, and I need to transpose it into a suitable format for inserting into my database using CakePHP. So, here's how I'm doing it:

```
public function submitApp($data) {
    $array = array(
        'Student' => array(
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
            'dob' => $data['dob'],
            'gender' => $data['gender']

        ),
        'Application' => array(
            'course_id' => $data['course_id'],
            'question1' => $data['question1'],
            'question2' => $data['question2'],
            'question3' => $data['question3'],
            'question4' => $data['question4'],
        ),
        'ApplicationQualification' => $data['Qualifications']
    );

    // Logic to save $array goes here
}
```

The problem is that sometimes not all of the keys in $data will be submitted to my app but I still want my app to work with what it gets.

I know that I can wrap each key in a conditional like this:

```
if (!isset($data['name'])) { $data['name'] = null; }
```

...and then building the array, but this seems like a pretty clumsy way of doing it. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple ternary statement

```
'name' => array_key_exists('name', $data) ? $data['name'] : null
```

Alternatively, you can set up a default array and then merge the given values in

```
$defaults = [
    'name' => null,
    'email' => null,
    // etc
    ];

$data = array_merge($defaults, $data);
```